# Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_5$. What is the number of elements of the vector space $F^3$ over $F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_5$. What is the number of elements of the vector space $F^3$ over $F$. Justify.

Is the answer be $^5C_3$? Please help.

Comment: What is the underlying set of $F^3$? Can you describe it?

Comment: @ASKASK $\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ has five elements. $F^3$ consists three touples. Then taking 3 from 5 elements be $^5C_3$

Comment: @Hayden Nothing more is given

Comment: ${}_5C_3$ is the amount of ways of choosing three *distinct* elements from $\mathbb{Z}_5$. The elements you're picking don't need to be distinct.

Comment: yes. u r right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A basis for $F^3$ is $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$. Therefore any element in $F^3$ takes the form $x=ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3$ for $a,b,c \in F$. How many different values can $a,b,c$ be? So therefore how many values can $x$ be?

Comment: How to find how many different values can a,b,c have

Comment: How many values can you pick for a? What about b? What about c?

Comment: a=5, b=5, c=5 ?

Comment: Correct. Now think of this problem: If I have five shirts to pick from and five pants to pick from, how many outfits can I make?

Comment: Is the answer be 5X5X5=125

Comment: @ASKASK +1 for continuing your explanation in the comments. I really like that, and this tshirt-shirt example.

Comment: @rama_ran That is correct